# How do I connect to SQL Server running in the host from a Hyper V VM?

Tags: sql-server, networking, hyper-v

On my PC (host) I've:

1. Installed SQL Server
2. Enabled Hyper V, created a new VM connected to "Default Switch" (internal).
3. Verified that sql server is running `telnet localhost 1433` and `telnet 172.17.169.1 1433` (hosts IP in the network created by Hyper V), see ip config output
4. Enabled TCP/IP in SQL Server Network Configuration:
5. I've added inbound firewall rule: Allow port 1433

[image]

However, I'm not able to connect to it from the VM using `telnet 172.17.169.1 1433`.

CMD Output (Host):

```
C:\>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

...

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::34f0:43ed:3e9b:8f6a%27
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.169.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

C:\>telnet 172.17.169.1 1433
.... OK
```

CMD Output (VM):

```
C:\Users\User>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mshome.net
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::99d0:eff8:c623:f82d%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.169.4
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.169.1

C:\Users\User>telnet 172.17.169.1 1433
Connecting To 172.17.169.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433: Connect failed
```

Comment: I suspect your PC doesn't route it's own IP network to itself; hence why localhost works, and the network IP doesn't. Why not, however, use the VM's IP (`192.168.241.106`)?

Comment: the telnet command is to `192.168.241.67` which is the IP address for what? (doesn't show show up in the question) also is the network running in Bridged mode or port forwarding?

Comment: @Larnu: I have restarted my PC and IPs have changed. Now I'm able to telnet from the host using host's IP, but still not from the VM

Comment: kshkarin: it was IP of the host in the network created by hyper v. The IP's have changed after restart and I've edited answer

Comment: @Liero what's the network mode in Hyper-V? If it's `Internal` as you mentioned then according to this [SSMS connectivity between a Hyper-V host and guest](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/06/hyper-v-getting-host-guest-connected/)  it should be working, the only difference in the `ipconfig` results is that the VM has a `default gateway` configured on the vNIC.

BTW what's the result of `PING` from VM guest to host?

Comment: It's internal and no, I cannot PINT the host

Comment: That seems more like a Hyper-V configuration issue at the networking level, if the guest is unable to ping the host then it definitely won't be able to connect on port 1433 to the SQL Server instance on the Host. What about removing the `default gateway` setting from both guest & host, or setting them to be the same?